# format datetime from linq query into selectlist for dropdown

Tags: vb.net, linq, formatting

No coffee. Brain. Not. Functioning.

I have this linq query here:

```
Public Function ListAllVisitDates() As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim visitdates = db.SchoolVisitDates.Select(Function(t) New SelectListItem() With {.Text = t.VisitDate, .Value = t.VisitDateID}).ToList()
    Return visitdates
End Function
```

It returns a long date of MM dd yyyy hh:mm blah blah which I'm populating a dropdown box with. I need it to be a short date of mm/dd/yyy. help?

**SOLVED**

This was stupid easy. After grabbing the values and creating my list of selectlistitem I just looped through the items and formatted them before passing it into my view:

```
Dim _VisitDates As New List(Of SelectListItem)
    Try
        _VisitDates = articlerepo.ListAllVisitDates()
        For Each item In _VisitDates
            item.Text = FormatDateTime(item.Text, DateFormat.ShortDate)
        Next
        ViewData("VisitDates") = _VisitDates
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This was stupid easy. After grabbing the values and creating my list of selectlistitem I just looped through the items and formatted them before passing it into my view:

```
Dim _VisitDates As New List(Of SelectListItem)
Try
    _VisitDates = articlerepo.ListAllVisitDates()
    For Each item In _VisitDates
        item.Text = FormatDateTime(item.Text, DateFormat.ShortDate)
    Next
    ViewData("VisitDates") = _VisitDates
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function ListAllVisitDates() As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim visitdates = db.SchoolVisitDates.Select(Function(t) New SelectListItem() With {.Text = t.VisitDate.ToString("d"), .Value = t.VisitDateID}).ToList()
    Return visitdates
End Function
```

Calling ToString("d") on the DateTime will return the date formatted as d/M/yyyy (as would NickLarsen's answer).

Comment: I gave that a shot, but I keep getting an exception.
"Conversion from string "d" to type 'Integer' is not valid".
I don't know why it's trying to convert it to an integer...
I'm calling this function like this:Dim VisitDates As New List(Of SelectListItem)
VisitDates = articlerepo.ListAllVisitDates()

Comment: What is the type of the t.VisitDate property?  Is it a DateTime or an Integer?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `DateTime`, have you tried using `.ToShortDateString()`?

Comment: There isn't a command like that. I've tried Format(t.visitdate, vbshortdate) and .ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") but they didn't work :/

Comment: What is the type of `VisitDate`?

Comment: I mean `t.VisitDate` not the `visitdates` variable.

Comment: That is a DateTime field in my sql db. The values look like this in the db: 2010-11-19 00:00:00.000
I just want the 2010-11-19 to be in the selectlist